# vba error using .Navigate to web page

Tags: excel, web-services, vba

folks,
i can successfully reach a web page from a UserForm within an Excel workbook and retrieve a website print image using .Navigate; i can even switch to a second web page and retrieve a website print image. but i get a 'script' error, either as i retrieve the first webpage, or as i retrieve the second web page. if i click 'yes' to continue running the script, it proceeds without issue. i don't have sufficient 'debug' experience to follow what is throwing the error. so, if you can help me find the 'root cause', maybe i can fix the error?
[this attachment is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UEVy.jpg)

the navigate module is here:

```
Private Sub optCandleChart_Change()
     Me.wbSCC.Navigate "http://stockcharts.com/h-sc/ui?s=" & txtTicker1.Value & "&p=D&b=5&g=0&id=t56926565868&r=1501858722627&cmd=print"
End Sub
```

when the UserForm launches, a ticker is fed from the Excel worksheet to the UserForm in txtTicker1.Value. it works, just hitting 'Yes' to continue running script is a bit tacky. is it because i am not setting up 'Change()' properly?

thanks,
ron

Comment: That error is from the web page and nothing to do with your VBA (at least, the VBA you've posted).  May be a browser incompatibility issue.

Comment: aha. ok, for learning purposes, what told you that? when the user form opens, no problem. then click a control, same website - then, that is where i get the error. maybe i need to 'close' the first graph somehow - gracefully - before i open the second graph? in the above, the first is a 'candle chart'; then there is exactly the same routine that opens a pnf chart. i don't really 'close' the first, the second just takes its' place. could that be the issue?

Comment: Only experience I guess, and that VBA errors don't present that kind of message.  It would be hard to debug the issue without the full code and workflow.

Comment: ok. since i have 'no' experience, now i don't feel bad i missed it. interesting: the first call to the website, to get the 'candle' charts, works w/o error. the second call for the 'pnf' charts has the error message. maybe i need to do something like a 'navigate complete' event that closes cleanly the first call as part of the second call? just a thought - the sub doesn't do any clean-up [i was too happy it actually worked to think about a full workflow procedure]. anyway, thanks again for the help